# Jquery: Scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I have this code:

```
<div class="container citiestop">
        <div class="columns">
            <a href="/{{$locale}}/contact#bcn" class="column is-4 citytop city-1-top red click-preloader" >
                <div id="tobcn">Barcelona.</div>
            </a>
            <a href="/{{$locale}}/contact#mad" class="column is-4 citytop city-2-top green click-preloader">
                <div id="tomadrid">Madrid.</div>
            </a>
            <a href="/{{$locale}}/contact#mex" class="column is-4 citytop city-3-top blue click-preloader">
                <div>@include('includes.trans',['es'=>'México', 'en'=>'Mexico']).</div>
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

And in the bottom on the page I have 3 divs with ids: `bcn`, `mad` and `mex`.

I'm trying to do this with jQuery:

```
$('#tobcn').click = function () {
     $(document).scrollTo('#bcn');
}
```

When I click go to the URL of href but doesn't scroll.

What's wrong with the code? No error appears.

Thanks a lot, and if you need more information feel free to ask for it.

**UPDATE**

```
  <div class="container cities">
        <div class="columns">
            <a href="/{{$locale}}/contact#bcn" class="column is-4 city city-1 red click-preloader scroller" data-scroller="bcn">
                <img src="/assets/img/contact/city-1.gif" alt="Barcelona">
                <div>Barcelona.</div>
            </a>
            <a href="/{{$locale}}/contact#mad" class="column is-4 city city-2 green click-preloader scroller" data-scroller="mad">
                <img src="/assets/img/contact/city-2.gif" alt="Madrid">
                <div>Madrid.</div>
            </a>
            <a href="/{{$locale}}/contact#mex" class="column is-4 city city-3 blue click-preloader scroller" data-scroller="mex">
                <img src="/assets/img/contact/city-3.gif" alt="México">
                <div>@include('includes.trans',['es'=>'México', 'en'=>'Mexico']).</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".scroller").click(function (){
        var dataScroller = $(this).data('scroller'); 
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + dataScroller).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });

     });
```

Comment: That's not how you add a click handler in jQuery http://api.jquery.com/click. Your logic for scrolling to the element isn't correct either, as there's no `scrollTo()` function. You need to implement that  yourself. See the duplicate for more info

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:
**HTML :**

```
<div class="container citiestop">
    <div class="columns">
        <a href="/{{$locale}}/contact#bcn" class="column is-4 citytop city-1-top red click-preloader scroller" data-scroller="bcn">
            <div id="tobcn">Barcelona.</div>
        </a>
        <a href="/{{$locale}}/contact#mad" class="column is-4 citytop city-2-top green click-preloader scroller" data-scroller="mad">
            <div id="tomadrid">Madrid.</div>
        </a>
        <a href="/{{$locale}}/contact#mex" class="column is-4 citytop city-3-top blue click-preloader scroller" data-scroller="mex">
            <div>@include('includes.trans',['es'=>'México', 'en'=>'Mexico']).</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(".scroller").click(function (){
    var dataScroller = $(this).data('scroller'); 
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + dataScroller).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

This will work dynamically through document.

**UPDATE**
You can use the same code at another page to work it. Just follow below steps:

**1)** Use same JQuery code
**2)** Use `scroller` class and data attribute like: `<a href="/{{$locale}}/contact#VALUE" class="scroller" data-scroller="VALUE">`, replace `VALUE` with your element id which you want to scroll to.

**For other page**, use below JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Scroll for opened page having hash value...
    if(window.location.hash){
        var dataScroller = window.location.hash.substr(1);          
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + dataScroller).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }

    //Scroll for sam page event...
    $(".scroller").click(function (){
        var dataScroller = $(this).data('scroller'); 
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + dataScroller).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi. If the html it's in the same blade than the id bcn,mad,mex works perfectly, but if it's on other blade go to /{{$locale}}/contact#id but don't make the scroll.

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer: As I mentioned, *This will work dynamically through document.*, just use same JQuery code and add `scroller` as class and `data-scroller="YOUR#VALUE"` into`<a>`. It should work for other too.

Comment: Scroller is on class in your code too, i try it putting the value in data-scroller but don't work. Can you edit your answer and put one example? Thanks a lot

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer: Check my *UPDATE*

Comment: Not working, maybe I can't see the error on my code, I update the question with my code. Sorry and please check it

Comment: Check your browser console for JS error?

Comment: I check it, any error appears.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152536/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-lluis-puig-ferrer).